# Can we know the absolute truth?

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, emes-truth-honesty

I've encountered Jewish and non-Jewish thinkers suggest that we, as finite creatures, cannot know the absolute, objective truth. All we can do (in This World), I've heard suggested, is to approach (in an asymptotic sense) the absolute truth through dialectic synthesis (i.e. thesis, antithesis, synthesis).

By absolute truth, I refer to knowledge of any thing in and of itself (i.e. the *noumenon*, or Kant's "*Ding an sich*") gained through the empirical world in which we live <sup>1</sup>.

What do our Sages (classical and recent) have to say on the matter?

---

<sup>1. H/T @Al Berko for suggesting to clarify</sup>

Comment: To answer this question, we need to differentiate theoretical and empirical truths. Math is an absolute theoretical truth and we everyone knows some (like 2+2=4 is the absolute truth). Empirical truth is a subject to our senses and therefore impossible to reach, for instance we can't even know if the world is real or simulated.

Comment: In sifre kabala they say that we don't deal with en sof or with keter Elion. There are domains of knowledge that we cannot afford. Moshe himself asked only הראני נא את כבודך

Comment: Read Emunos Vdeos by Rav Saadia Gaon

Comment: Also see the book "Torah and Reason" by Rav Chaim Zimmerman zt"l.

Comment: Shouldn't we have an absolute language in order to describe the absolute truth?

Comment: I think it's pretty clear that all we can know is the perception of things, as opposed to their essence. I.g. we can know what the Sun does to us, but not what it IS.